# How can I in R cleverly find previous time periods start and end?

Tags: r, xts, lubridate

I would in R like to find the previous periods beginning and end. A period is defined in minutes.

Would love the output as below.

```
library(lubridate)
timeNow <- now()
timeNow
# [1] "2019-04-17 11:17:09 CEST"

periodLength <- 60    #minutes
previousPeriodStart(timeNow, periodLength)
# [1] "2019-04-17 10:00:00 CEST"
previousPeriodEnd(timeNow, periodLength)
# [1] "2019-04-17 10:59:59 CEST"

periodLength <- 5    #minutes
previousPeriodStart(timeNow, periodLength)
# [1] "2019-04-17 11:10:00 CEST"
previousPeriodEnd(timeNow, periodLength)
# [1] "2019-04-17 11:14:59 CEST"
```

I understand how to build these functions in xts if I had a ts with data.
As I don't have a dataset for this example I can't use xts to.period functions. I instead just want to find the start and end.

What would be the most clever way of constructing the previousPeriodStart and previousPeriodEnd? Or should I just start doing some arithmetic with epoch/unix times?

Big thanks in advance.

--- EDIT ----
Since receiving an answer with a function that answers both start and end in same function this is of course much smarter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `lubridate` this can easily be done:

```
previousPeriod <- function(timeNow,periodLength)
{
  start <- floor_date(timeNow - minutes(60),"hour")
  end <- ceiling_date(timeNow - minutes(60),"hour") - seconds(1)
  return(c(start=start,end=end))
}

previousPeriod(timeNow,periodLength)

                    start                       end 
"2019-04-17 10:00:00 UTC" "2019-04-17 10:59:59 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks for great suggestion using floor/celiling_date. I didn't realise these existed. I have marked this as correct as you were slightly faster than second answer by LocoGris. I have also sent my own slight refactoring of your code to add possibility for not only hour intervals.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
library(lubridate)
timeNow <- now()

period = 60

floor_date(timeNow, unit="hour")-minutes(period)+minutes( trunc(minute(timeNow)/period)*period)
floor_date(timeNow, unit="hour")-minutes(period)+minutes( trunc(minute(timeNow)/period)*period)+minutes(period)-seconds(1)

period = 5

floor_date(timeNow, unit="hour")-minutes(period)+minutes( trunc(minute(timeNow)/period)*period)
floor_date(timeNow, unit="hour")-minutes(period)+minutes( trunc(minute(timeNow)/period)*period)+minutes(period)-seconds(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for great suggestion in using floor_date. I have marked the other answer by Julian_Hn as correct as that answer was slightly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Building on both other answers of using floor_date I have improved the quickest answer to also include working code for other minute intervals than full hour.

```
previousPeriods <- function(timeNow, periodLength)
{
  periodPhrase <- paste0(periodLength, " mins")  # To create periods such as "5 mins"
  start <- floor_date(timeNow - minutes(periodLength), periodPhrase)
  end <- ceiling_date(timeNow - minutes(periodLength), periodPhrase) - seconds(1)
  return(c(start=start,end=end))
}
```

Once again thanks for all help with quick answers.